# SQL: How to join two rows on the same table, based on the same timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is a data output table in postgreSQL.
I am looking for a way to join rows 7 and 8 on the timestamp condition to remove the [null] values.

[image: databaseSnapshot]

This is the expected output I am looking for.
So that I will only have one row when the timestamp matches.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
05:32:33          | Pump2Stop           | 49                    
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea how can this be done?

Comment: There'll only be two rows with matching timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you only ever have one record per timestamp with a non-null value in a specific column, try this:

```
SELECT to_timestamp, MAX(str_v), MAX(long_v)
FROM table
GROUP BY to_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-join

```
select stp.to_timestamp, 
       stp.str_v,
       strt.long_v
from the_table stp
  join the_table strt 
    on stp.to_timestamp = strt.to_timestamp
   and strt.str_v is null
where stp.str_v = 'Pump2Stop'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want all rows -- with the specified rows combined.  Based on your comment, I think this does what you want:

```
select t1.to_timestamp, t1.str_v
       coalesce(t2.long_v, t1.long_v)
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t.to_timestamp = t2.to_timestamp and
        t.str_v in ('Pump2Stop', 'Pump2Stop')
where t1.str_v is not null;
```

You can also use a window function:

```
select t.to_timestamp, t.str_v,
       coalesce(long_v, imputed_long_v) as long_v
from (select t.*,
             max(long_v) over (partition by to_timestamp) as imputed_long_v
      from t
     ) t
where str_v is not null;
```